# How to change theme in SWT application

Tags: java, swt

I'm new to developing SWT applications and am looking for an easy way to change the theme of a small application which I have already developed.

After doing some googling I'm able to tell that there seems to be something called presentations which seems like a way I can download a ready made theme and just apply it to my application. Is that right?

Alternatively can anyone point me to a good tutorial on the right way to go about it?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just talking about SWT without Ecipse RCP, then there is no way to theme the application.

One of the main advantage of SWT is that it uses OS resources to resemble system applications. Using themes would contradict this approach.

If you are however using Eclipse RCP 4, look at @Ran's answer.

Comment: Thanks Baz. It is just a stand alone application without the Rich Client Platform. So you are saying that to try and customize colors and add background images etc is against the principles of SWT?

Comment: @user1600419 Well, then you can't use themes. The only thing you could do is create custom widgets. If you really *need* simple theme switching, you might be better off with [AWT/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) instead. Please consider upvoting and accepting my answer.

Comment: Tks Baz. Ok so I understand now. There is now easy way of changing the look and feel of my widgets. If I want the widgets customized I'll have to do it the hard way and customize myself.

Comment: Is there any way to make the color theme constant at any os anytime? can I forcibly set a default one theme for my application?

Answer (score 1):

The `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme` extension point supports the creation of extensions for themes. This extension defines an ID for the style and a pointer to the CSS file.

You can also define the default theme via the cssTheme property in your org.eclipse.core.runtime.products extension. This can also be used to define a fixed styling.

To switch the styling you use the `IThemeEngine`.

```
package com.example.e4.rcp.todo.handlers;

import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Execute;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme.IThemeEngine;

public class ThemeSwitchHandler {
  // Remember the state
  static boolean defaulttheme= true;
  @Execute
  public void switchTheme(IThemeEngine engine) {
    System.out.println("ThemeSwitchHandler called");
    // The last argument controls
    // whether the change should be persisted and
    // restored on restart
    if (!defaulttheme) {
      engine.setTheme("com.vogella.e4.todo.defaulttheme", true);

    } else {
      engine.setTheme("com.vogella.e4.todo.redtheme", true);
    }
    defaulttheme= !defaulttheme;
  }
}
```

Comment: So how exactly is this ThemeSwitchHandler to be used?